# python: Timer with a input time and input interval

Tags: python, input, timer

thank you for viewing my question.

I'm completely new to python, and I'm having some trouble with coding a timer with input and an input interval.
I'm trying to have a customizable length of time with a customizable interval for printing a message.
Could anyone help out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your problem and what you explained to me in the comments, the following code will solve your problem:

```py
import threading
import time

y = int(input("interval: "))
x = int(input("time: "))
running = True

def countdown(x):
    while x > 0:
        print(x)
        x -= 1
        time.sleep(1)

def sound(y):
    while running is True:
        time.sleep(y)
        print("interval test")

sound_thread = threading.Thread(target=sound, args=(y,))
sound_thread.start()

countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(x,))
countdown_thread.start()
countdown_thread.join()

running = False
print("done")
```

Comment: When i enter my interval value and run for eksampel 10 in time and 2 in interval, there isnt printed the "interval test" every 2 seconds. Thats my main issue. Thanks by the way.

Comment: If i set interval to 2 and timer to 10, id like it to be 10, 9 ,interval test, 8, 7, interval test, and so on. but im afraid i dont know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, got it!

You can create two threads, for `sound(y)` and `countdown(x)`, the'll run at the same time and when the `countdown(x)` finishes, you can send an exit(1) to finish your application.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask so much but would it be something like this?:                                                                             countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target = countdown, args=(x,))
countdown_thread.start()
sound_thread = threading.Thread(target = sound, args=(y,))
sound_thread.start() im pretty unsure of this, sorry

Comment: No problem buddy! Just updated my answer with a code example!

Comment: Thank you so much, ive really learned alot. you are my hero!

Comment: But do you know how to get rid of the last interval test after done, when i run the program, an interval test is run after the last done message?

Comment: You can call `os._exit(0)` after the `countdown_thread.join()` and it will guarantee that the Python process will finish. Remember to `import os`.
If you use that, you can remove the `running` flag from the code, and let de `sound()` while in an infinite loop.